# Remove single quotes from string in words

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need help to remove single quotes from strings with REGEX in VB.NET. I need to remove single quotes from words, but not single quotes that define a string like:

- Her is som’e string --> Her is some string
- Her ‘is som’e’ string --> Her ‘is some’ string
- He’r ‘is some’ string --> Her ‘is some’ string
- Her ‘is some’ st’ri’ng --> Her ‘is some’ string

I suppose that the logic would be that if there is no space on either side of the ‘ then it should be removed else it should be left.
Peter Schwennesen

Answer (score 0):

Use This for remove single quotes in VB....

```
  Dim pattern As String = "\'+" 
  Dim replacement As String = "" 
  Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
  Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)
```

Comment: thansk, but I do not want to remove all quotes, only the one inside words, not the one definins a string in the text. the quote "som'e" here should be removed so that it change to "some" but the one "Here is 'som'e' string",  outside should not be remove, the string "Here is 'som'e' string" should end out to be: "Here is 'some' string"
Peter Schwennesen

Comment: How could you possibly tell which `'` is part of a pair and which one is the odd one out? I think you might need to take a different approach. What about `"Here is 'some' strin'g"`?

Comment: From his comment I think he is searching for this regex: \b’\b   (http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%e2%80%99%5cb&i=Her+is+som%e2%80%99e+string+%0d%0aHer+%e2%80%98is+som%e2%80%99e%e2%80%99+string%0d%0aHe%e2%80%99r+%e2%80%98is+some%e2%80%99+string+%0d%0aHer+%e2%80%98is+some%e2%80%99+st%e2%80%99ri%e2%80%99ng)

Comment: Your also try this [a-z]+\'[a-z]+